# 16.10 Drives not visible in Files

Tags: mount

after a recent upgrade to 16.10 several of my drives are not visible in Files.  I can click on other locations to access the drives, but I would prefer to have them show up as mounted drives.

Below is the output of blkid from terminal:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="7b79aafa-e198-421b-8d30-320e10ac1f80" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="75285aea-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="4C462g-h2Mu-u1Tl-Vgjy-H5UE-hndN-11s1ce" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="75285aea-05"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Backups" UUID="16107F884ABE06B5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7e1be820-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Other Stuff" UUID="333134700AD8FF48" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7e1be820-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="7694EA8094EA426B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7e1be820-03"
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="HP_RECOVERY" UUID="8E505347505334E5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7e1be820-04"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="D474442C74441420" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="ef6d8143-01"
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="TV Shows" UUID="03F243B41B8319C9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="ef6d8143-02"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="DA6AA2736AA24C57" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a00f14a2-01"
/dev/sdd2: LABEL="Movies" UUID="aadcdb8b-32db-4758-be77-e6f94a9fee17" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a00f14a2-02"
/dev/sdd3: UUID="EE20E88F20E85FD7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a00f14a2-03"
/dev/sde1: LABEL="Seagate Expansion Drive" UUID="1CA057FDA057DBB8" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="d1bb5c06-da4d-4d98-a4cd-40183e956ddc" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="e8f1bcb2-e8f2-4d22-87b6-286b5dbd97f0" TYPE="swap"


This is the contents of /etc/fstab:

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0    $
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7b79aafa-e198-421b-8d30-320e10ac1f80 /boot           ext2    defaults $
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0    $
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/DA6AA2736AA24C57 /mnt/DA6AA2736AA24C57 auto nosuid,nodev,$
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5dabd5d6-6ab2-478a-9b41-c4b45311c8be /mnt/5dabd5d6-6ab2-4$
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5004f9b8fb2-part1 /mnt/wwn-0x5000c5004f9b8fb2-pa$
/dev/disk/by-uuid/aadcdb8b-32db-4758-be77-e6f94a9fee17 /mnt/aadcdb8b-32db-4$
LABEL=TV\040Shows /mnt/TV\040Shows auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

How do I need to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the disks utility.  Hit the Super key (aka the Windows key), and search for disks.  The utility you want looks like an HDD with a wrench on it.

This will show every connected drive.  You should be able to select the drive/partition you want and chose mount (the play button) or unmount (the stop button).  The drive will show up in files, and the disks utility will tell you where it's mounted in the file system under Contents.

I can't write/find a tutorial on how to use this app, but it's fairly intuitive (very similar to the windows disk management GUI).

Word of warning: don't just click willy nilly, hover over ever option and make sure the pop-up text is what you're expecting.. If it asks for your password, make sure you know EXACTLY what you're doing.  This utility will let you WIPE OUT YOUR DRIVES if you tell it to.